# Using a Comparator, how can I determine match quality between objects, or is there a better way

Tags: java, comparator

I have a code-base where I am trying to determine similarities between offered services. These services have categories. However, I want to determine likeness by comparing the set of categories, the time it takes to do the service, and the amount the service costs. I have written the code, and it's working as expected (I think), but I get the sense I am missing something, so I wanted to put it here to get some feedback, and gain some understanding.

**Test**

```
@Test
public void testSimilarProjectComparatorSorting() {
    List<ProjectService> projectServices = createProjectServices();

    System.out.println(projectServices);

    projectServices.sort(new SimilarProjectComparator());

    System.out.println(projectServices);

    // Assertions
}

public static List<ProjectService> createProjectServices() {
    List<ProjectService> projectServices = new ArrayList<>();

    ProjectService projectService = new ProjectService();
    projectService.setAmount(new BigDecimal(1800));
    projectService.setDifficultyScale(Estimation.FIVE);

    Category genericCat = new Category();
    genericCat.setName("Generic");
    genericCat.setSlug("generic");

    Category listingCat = new Category();
    listingCat.setName("Listing");
    listingCat.setSlug("listing");

    Category webCat = new Category();
    webCat.setName("Web");
    webCat.setSlug("web");

    projectService.setCategories(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(genericCat, listingCat, webCat)));

    projectServices.add(projectService);

    projectService = new ProjectService();
    projectService.setAmount(new BigDecimal(800));
    projectService.setDifficultyScale(Estimation.THREE);

    Category outliningCat = new Category();
    outliningCat.setName("Outlining");
    outliningCat.setSlug("outlining");

    Category bullHeadedCat = new Category();
    bullHeadedCat.setName("Bull-Headed");
    bullHeadedCat.setSlug("bull-headed");

    projectService.setCategories(
            new HashSet<>(
                    Arrays.asList(
                            outliningCat,
                            bullHeadedCat,
                            webCat
                    )
            )
    );

    projectServices.add(projectService);

    projectService = new ProjectService();
    projectService.setAmount(new BigDecimal(1500));
    projectService.setDifficultyScale(Estimation.FIVE);

    Category writingCat = new Category();
    writingCat.setName("Writing");
    writingCat.setSlug("writing");

    projectService.setCategories(
            new HashSet<>(
                    Arrays.asList(
                            writingCat,
                            genericCat,
                            listingCat
                    )
            )
    );

    projectServices.add(projectService);

    projectService = new ProjectService();
    projectService.setAmount(new BigDecimal(1400));
    projectService.setDifficultyScale(Estimation.TWO);

    projectService.setCategories(
            new HashSet<>(
                    Arrays.asList(
                            writingCat,
                            genericCat,
                            listingCat,
                            webCat
                    )
            )
    );

    projectServices.add(projectService);

    return projectServices;
}
```

**Code**

```
public class SimilarProjectComparator implements Comparator<ProjectService> {
    @Override
    public int compare(ProjectService o1, ProjectService o2) {
        Set<Category> o1CategorySet = o1.getCategories();
        Set<Category> o2CategorySet = o2.getCategories();
        Integer categoryMatch = 0;
        Double matchQuality = 0.0;

        if (o1CategorySet != null && o2CategorySet != null) {
            for (Category o1Category : o1CategorySet) {
                for (Category o2Category : o2CategorySet) {
                    Integer match = o1Category.getName().compareTo(o2Category.getName());
                    if (match > 0) {
                        categoryMatch++;
                    } else {
                        categoryMatch--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (categoryMatch > 0) {
            matchQuality++;
        } else {
            matchQuality--;
        }

        Integer scaleMatch = o1.getDifficultyScale().getEstimation().compareTo(
                o2.getDifficultyScale().getEstimation()
        );

        if (scaleMatch > 0) {
            matchQuality++;
        } else {
            matchQuality--;
        }

        Integer amountMatch = o1.getAmount().compareTo(o2.getAmount());

        if (amountMatch > 0) {
            matchQuality++;
        } else {
            matchQuality--;
        }

        return matchQuality.intValue();
    }
}
```

I would assume the order would be (judging by how similar the categories are): 1400, 1500, 800, then 1800. However, the actual order is: 800, 1400, 1500, 1800. I am new to comparators, and am not sure I am doing this right. **Is there something I'm missing or is this working correctly, and it's my assumptions that are incorrect?** I understand that I am trying to determine the quality of the object match using 3 different props, so how similar the categories are doesn't guarantee the order I mentioned above, unless it held more weight. Which I don't think is necessary from a business logic standpoint. I am just new to comparators, and trying to understand this. Thanks for any help ahead of time!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because requests to review "real" *working* code should go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Meaning: if you want us to find a "bug" in your code, then consider to "compress" your code into a real [mcve]. Dropping serious amounts of production code isnt a good start to figure where/if there is a bug.

Comment: I was going to post it in the code review stack exchange but the FAQ said it was only for _working_ examples. I don't know if this is working, because I am questioning the loop with the categories. That is what my question involves: is this loop the correct way to determine the equality of a set of objects inside a comparator.

Comment: I agree, then having it here is ok. But as said, then you *could* work on reducing the input.

Comment: You mean not trying to do so much inside the comparator? I thought about just comparing the estimate and amount, my only concern is in the instance where I had a project that was the same estimate and slightly similar amount, and was categorized much differently (maybe it was a UI project, verses an Engineering one) could that create confusion when trying to find likeness?

Comment: In your comparator you use if (match >0) then matchQuality++ else matchQuality--. What if match == 0 indicating the two elements are equal?

Comment: That's a good point. If they are equal, maybe I should increment by two, since I am trying to find similar projects?

Comment: Maybe you add 1 to the quality if the match is 0, otherwise subtract 1.

Comment: You should be using `int` and `double`, not Integer and Double.  The latter are objects, which means every increment or other mathematical operation creates a new object.  With a collection of any significant size, expect this to cause a slowdown as garbage collection kicks in.

Comment: Thanks @VGR I appreciate the perf advice! I'll incorporate that into my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for similarities. If comparing two elements results in 0 than those elements are identical. Otherwise they are not. I changed your routine to:

```
public int compare(ProjectService o1, ProjectService o2) {
    Set<Category> o1CategorySet = o1.getCategories();
    Set<Category> o2CategorySet = o2.getCategories();
    int categoryMatch = 0;
    double matchQuality = 0.0;

    if ((o1CategorySet != null) && (o2CategorySet != null)) {
        for (Category o1Category : o1CategorySet) {
            for (Category o2Category : o2CategorySet) {
                int match = o1Category.getName().compareTo(o2Category.getName());
                if (match == 0) {
                    categoryMatch++;
                } else {
                    categoryMatch--;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (categoryMatch == 0) {
        matchQuality++;
    } else {
        matchQuality--;
    }

    int scaleMatch = o1.getDifficultyScale().getEstimation().compareTo(o2.getDifficultyScale().getEstimation());

    if (scaleMatch == 0) {
        matchQuality++;
    } else {
        matchQuality--;
    }

    int amountMatch = o1.getAmount().compareTo(o2.getAmount());

    if (amountMatch == 0) {
        matchQuality++;
    } else {
        matchQuality--;
    }

    return (int) matchQuality;
}
```

With that the sorting should be working.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, thanks for the help!